# Set a variable delay for the timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which I use to display response messages in my modals.

```
// Show response message
function show_response_message_modal(msg,elementId){
    $('#'+elementId+' #responseMessage').html(msg)
    $('#'+elementId+' #message_container').show(msg);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#'+elementId+' #message_container').hide()
        $('#'+elementId+' #responseMessage').html('')
    }, 4000)
}
```

In my ajax response:

```
show_response_message_modal('Please insert all the required fields','settingsModal')
```

This works just fine.

Due to the fact that each message has a variable length I would like to display each message for a defined amount of seconds which I will set as paramenter in the function. It will be annoying to wait 4 seconds just for a 'Posted successfully' message while you will not be able to totally read a longer message.

I have tried this:

```
function show_response_message_modal(msg,elementId,delay){
    $('#'+elementId+' #responseMessage').html(msg)
    $('#'+elementId+' #message_container').show(msg);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#'+elementId+' #message_container').hide()
        $('#'+elementId+' #responseMessage').html('')
    }, delay)
}

show_response_message_modal('Please insert all the required fields','settingsModal',3000)
```

But unfortunately this breaks my code.

Any advise?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see why it would break your code... Any error messages???

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Side note, try to be consistent with your naming. you have responseMessage and message_container...

Comment: Doesn't break here https://jsfiddle.net/xteLxpgL/13/#&togetherjs=bRw6KMstiO

Comment: Also remove msg from the show() function

Comment: Thank you guys, now I am sure this should work normally I have double checked everything and I found that I forgot the set the third parameter in one of the calls and this was causing the trouble. The strange is that I was not getting any error in the console. Have nice coding. One up to all